# Fullcalendar wrong placement of events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar in jquery dialog that is open when I click a button.

The calendar looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    calendar = $( "#calendar" ).fullCalendar({
        height: 400,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek,month'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        slotDuration: '00:60:00',
        slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
        timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
        firstDay: 1,
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectOverlap: false,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        editable: false,
        eventStartEditable: false,
        eventDurationEditable: false,
        eventLimit: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
            var title = prompt('Purpose of this booking:');
            var eventData;
            if (title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

        events: [
            {
                title: 'Test1',
                start: '2016-05-26T10:00:00',
                end: '2016-05-26T16:00:00',
                allDay: false

            },
            {
                title: 'Test2',
                start: '2016-05-27T14:00:00',
                end: '2016-05-27T18:00:00',   
                allDay: false
            }
        ]   
    });
} );

$(function() {
    dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 610,
        width: 900,
        modal: true
    });

    $( ".btn-book" ).button().on( "click", function() {
        dialog.dialog( "open" );
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    });
});
</script> 

<button class='btn-book' type='button'>Book</button>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Book resource">
    <form>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is how it renders the events the first time:
[image]

As you can see, the events are not placed properly, the times don't match with the rows shown by the calendar...

Interestingly, if I enter a new event manually, then everything moves a bit and aligns automatically matching the times.

[image]

Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: Add your remaining codes too.

Comment: @frnt added. It is a simplification of the whole code, but with that I can reproduce the same error.

Comment: It's working fine on my device, just try by removing height of 400 which you have added at starting 

calendar = $( "#calendar" ).fullCalendar({ height: 400,

Allow it to take viewport height automatically.

Comment: I added the example online. Check it out http://52.11.159.93/testcalendar/test.html

Comment: This is an old question but I am facing the same issue. Any solution/workaround?